# Change color of selected bar in Achartengine

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I have to change the color of the particular bar that is selected by the user in bar chart.
When ever user select the bar I want to change the color of that bar and again if user change the selection of bar the last selected bar will show as default color.

**Note:** I saw in one post that I have to use one more series that contain the selected bar so you can achieve that. But I need some sample code to understand that.

```
private String[] mMonth = new String[] { "January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
int[] x = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int[] income = { 2000, 2500, 2700, 3000, 2800, 3500, 3700, 3800 };
public static final String TYPE = "type";
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = getDemoDataset();
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = getDemoRenderer();
private GraphicalView mChartView;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xy_chart);
    if (mChartView == null) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
        layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    } else {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }

    mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // handle the click event on the chart
              SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
              if (seriesSelection == null) {
                Toast.makeText(NewTest.this, "No chart element", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } else {  


                  for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                      SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex());
                      renderer.setColor(Color.RED);  
                    }


                    mChartView.repaint();

                // display information of the clicked point
                Toast.makeText(
                        NewTest.this,
                    "Chart element in series index " + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
                        + " data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was clicked"
                        + " closest point value X=" + seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", Y="
                        + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        }
    });

}

 private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset() {

        XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Income");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            incomeSeries.add(i, income[i]);
        }

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
        return dataset;

    }

 private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getDemoRenderer() {
        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer =  new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        incomeRenderer.setChartValuesSpacing(15);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(15);
        multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.3f);
        multiRenderer.setBarWidth(30);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Income Chart");
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Year 2013");
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Amount in Dollars");
        //multiRenderer.setZoomLimits(1.0,0.7,1.0,3000.0);
        multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        //multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
        //multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
        multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(7);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(4000);

        multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {30, 50, 20, 10});
        multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        multiRenderer.setShowGridX(true);


        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
        }

        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
        return multiRenderer;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I see you are handling the click events on the chart view. Every bar series has its own color. In order to have a bar with a different color, it has to belong to another series. In this case, you will have to remove the bar from the series it belongs to and add another series with only one item, the selected bar.

On the second click, reverse the operation above.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still interested in this. There is no need to add another series (and it will be drawn separately afaik). You could just extend the chart and do the drawing as in the example below. (in my project I use my own scrolling/zooming through GestureDetector and ScaleGestureDetector, and instead of onClick I use onSingleTapUp of GestureDetector). Use getView from the class below to get the instance of the chart's view:

```
public class SelectableBarChart extends BarChart {

private int selectedSeriesIndex = -1;
private int selectedBar = -1;
private final int highlightColor;
private OnBarSelectedListener barSelectedListener;

public static interface OnBarSelectedListener {
    void onBarSelected(SeriesSelection seriesSelection);
}

public void setBarSelectedListener(OnBarSelectedListener barSelectedListener) {
    this.barSelectedListener = barSelectedListener;
}

public static GraphicalView getView(Context context, XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, Type type, int highlightColor) {
    final SelectableBarChart chart = new SelectableBarChart(dataset, renderer, type, highlightColor);
    final GraphicalView graphicalView = new GraphicalView(context, chart);
    graphicalView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chart.onClick(graphicalView);
        }
    });
    return graphicalView;
}

public void onClick(GraphicalView view) {
    onSelectionTap(view, view.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint());
}

protected void onSelectionTap(GraphicalView view, SeriesSelection seriesSelection) {
    if (seriesSelection != null) {
        selectedSeriesIndex = seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex();
        XYSeries selectedSeries = getDataset().getSeriesAt(selectedSeriesIndex);
        selectedBar = selectedSeries.getIndexForKey(seriesSelection.getXValue());
    }
    if (barSelectedListener != null)
        barSelectedListener.onBarSelected(seriesSelection);
    view.repaint();
}

@Override
public void drawSeries(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, List<Float> points, SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer, float yAxisValue, int seriesIndex, int startIndex) {
    int seriesNr = mDataset.getSeriesCount();
    boolean selectedSeries = seriesIndex == selectedSeriesIndex;
    int length = points.size();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    float halfDiffX = getHalfDiffX(points, length, seriesNr);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        paint.setColor(selectedSeries && i == 2*(selectedBar-startIndex) ? highlightColor : seriesRenderer.getColor());
        float x = points.get(i);
        float y = points.get(i + 1);
        drawBar(canvas, x, yAxisValue, x, y, halfDiffX, seriesNr, seriesIndex, paint);
    }
    paint.setColor(seriesRenderer.getColor());
}
```

}